# Datatable TableTools with bootstrap not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, tabletools

Got Datatable to work.  Now trying to apply the extra Tabletools (so i can export table to csv).

I can see the export to csv. Am i missing something? I have applied(as suggested)

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'T><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": [
            "copy",
            "print",
            {
                "sExtends":    "collection",
                "sButtonText": 'Save <span class="caret" />',
                "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
            }
        ]
    }
    } );
} );
```

I am using the 'jquery-datatables-rails' gem, which it says it supports table tools.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: I am trying to use the export to csv option from table tools. It won't show up above the table as the examples show.

Comment: Yes, but does the buttons show? It is the functionality that dosent work or what?

Comment: dataTables works. The buttons do not show for tabletools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you miss the flash-object.

If it is 1.91. Add this to your `dataTable{(` code (you must realize that the path depends on your setup, so this is just an example)

```
sSwfPath: "DataTables-1.9.1/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
```

Comment: Right. I thought the gem would take care of that for me, no? I tried that path and it did not work for me.

Comment: i dont know ror, but it must be there if they claim it is included in the gem - or, you could link to som external resource. Your own site, you can place the .swf anywhere

Comment: See this http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/swf_path.html

Comment: Try a site that i Know holding the swf sSwfPath: "DataTables-http://allearter-databasen.dk/1.9.1/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",

Comment: http://allearter-databasen.dk/DataTables-1.9.1/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf

Comment: The gem does include it. Somebody also raised the same issue inside the gems github. Works on the their site but not for me :(

Comment: does the gem include DataTables-1.9.1/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf

Comment: I am not sure. How would i check? The documentation says it includes the files for TableTools i would only assume it does?

Comment: I am not very familiar with RoR. Is there an working example you can copy/paste from? The missing .swf is the most common reason people experience when their tabletools not works.

Comment: yeah there is definitely an example on the data table website. http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/bootstrap.html      btw, thank you for helping me! It could be the .swf missing I just don't know how the gem handles the paths.